# .htaccess not working even though other rules work

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to do a redirect to another site. The following rule works perfectly for all the other rules within my `.htacces` but the following rule does not seem to work and i can'r figure out why, after lots of try and error.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldexample.com$ 
RewriteRule ^folder3/page.php?value=(.*)$ http://newexample.com/folder1/page.php?value=$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

I tried the following which redirected but without the value within `(.*)` added

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldexample.com$ 
RewriteRule ^folder3/page.php?(.*)$ http://newexample.com/folder1/page.php?$1 [L,R=301,NC]
```

Could this be an issue with the `=` symbbol? I tried escaping it and escaping the `.` also but to no avail

Comment: OK. please provide full `.htaccess` content, to be more clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't match against the query string (everything after the **?**) in a rewrite rule, you need to use a `RewriteCond` and match against the `%{QUERY_STRING}`. However, it looks like you're just trying to pass the query string along, unchanged. So you don't need to mess with any of it:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.oldexample.com$ 
RewriteRule ^folder3/page.php$ http://newexample.com/folder1/page.php [L,R=301,NC]
```

The query string will get appended automatically. You need to make sure this rule is above any routing rules as it needs to take place before any internal rewrites.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I need the value to be applied to the new URL as in the question, as this is a database driven page and the query is relevant. thanks.

Comment: @TheApptracker Like I said, the query string (the `?value=something`) will *automatically get appended*, so you don't need to do anything with it.